# Why do my VR avatar's hands clip through my chair object?

Tags: unity, collision-detection, collision-resolution, virtual-reality, motion-control

I have spent hours on this task and I feel it's high time I asked. My avatar hands go into my chair GameObject.

I added a box collider to the hands of my avatar and unchecked "Is Trigger". I also added a box collider to my chair and its "Is Trigger" is also unchecked. In addition to this, I added a Rigidbody to this GameObject and "collision detection" set to "continuous" hoping that the hands and the game object will collide without going into each other, but they still clip through one another.

I have also tried including Rigidbodies to the hands. Still the same. I have tried many of the solutions under similar problems, but the problem persists.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when they collide? Is the chair supposed to be knocked away?

Comment: Nothing. The chair should not be knocked away. The avatar hands should not just go inside the chair

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you move your (real) hands where the chair is?
If this is a VR project, your virtual hands are usually supposed to move (kinematically) in the virtual world to match your body movements. Do you expect your virtual hands to decouple from your physical hands when they crash into the virtual chair?

Comment: Yes, you are right about the movement of my virtual hands. I do not expect my virtual hands to decouple from my physical hands on colliding with the chair.  I just want the chair to be treated as/like a wall so that when the hands meet with it, they don't go inside the chair.

Comment: Your virtual hands follow your real hands. There is no way to prevent your real hands from moving to where the virtual chair is…